# Renaming Android app Bundle and APK (.aab and .apk) files with app name, version and build type - build.gradle.kts

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-build

How To change Android App Bundle/APK name (app.aab/app.apk) to reflect App version, App name and build type in `build.gradle.kts`

Here is the `build.gradle.kts`, I need to rename apk/aab here

```
android {
namespace = "com.example.app"
compileSdk = 34

val prop = Properties().apply {
    load(FileInputStream(File(rootProject.rootDir, "keystore.properties")))
}

signingConfigs {
    create("my_sign") {
        storeFile = file(prop.getProperty("storeFile"))
        storePassword = prop.getProperty("storePassword").toString()
        keyPassword = prop.getProperty("keyPassword").toString()
        keyAlias = prop.getProperty("keyAlias").toString()
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.example.app"
    minSdk = 24
    targetSdk = 34
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("my_sign")
}

buildTypes {

    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = true
        isShrinkResources = true
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
    debug {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        isShrinkResources = false
    }
}
```

I would be grateful for any code snippet, suggestions, references, or links.

Comment: Use the`archivesBaseName` property inside `defaultConfig` block

Comment: @JustinW Can you give some additional details about this?